# For loop to print numbers from 1-20 divisible by 2, second line for divisble 3third is for divisble by 4?

Tags: c#

I need an algorithm that prints 3 lines, first is for numbers from 1-20 divisble by 2, second is for divisble by 3, third is for divisble by 4.

```
for (int i = 1;i <20 ; i++)  
{     
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {     
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

i can't print the result in 3 seperate lines

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want this code:

```
for(int j = 2; j <= 4; j++)
{
    for(int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
    {
        if (i % j == 0)
            Console.Write("{0} ", i);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Think why this is a correct and elegant way to do your task.